# Required training data size for retraining Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

How much training data is required (minimum )for retraining Stanford NER models reliably ? If we generate manually annotated training data, would 10 thousand sentences be sufficient for training the model to extract entities - organization names and technology names?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of data required is not a simple calculation.  You have to take in to account the diversity of the training data as well as the diversity of the target data.  We did some experiments with the CoNLL 2003 data and found we could get 90% of the accuracy using the AllenNLP toolkit with 1/6 the data if we chose the tokens / sentences to train on carefully.  Essentially this meant training on a few sentences and seeing which tokens were most uncertain, and then adding sentences containing those tokens to the training set and repeating.

This means that you should not expect that 10K sentences is some sort of magic number.  If you have a large number of sentences to choose your training from you are better off coming up with a way of choosing diverse sentences.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit minimum amount of training data for retraining the NER model; in general, accuracy will continue to improve the more data you give it. My impression -- and I should emphasize that this is just my personal instinct -- is that 10k sentences is likely more or less sufficient to train a decent NER system. For instance, the CoNLL 2003 shared task trained on 15k sentences (http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/pdf/14247tjo.pdf).